# How do I know the system call for a particular command?

Tags: command-line

I'm new in Ubuntu and I have this question about `strace ls` command. When I'm run this command it gives all the system calls. What if I need to know the system calls for a specific command, for example if I run the command `mkdir`? I want to know what are the system calls for this particular command.

Its helps me a lot in my studies. Thank a lot.

Comment: I didn't get this. `strace ls` does give you the system calls for `ls`, so what exactly do you intend to know?

Comment: its gives me the whole system calls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like you do `strace ls`, you should do `strace mkdir` which will give you list of all calls made by `mkdir` like as sample below from my PC:

```
execve("/bin/mkdir", ["mkdir"], [/* 37 vars */]) = 0
brk(0)                                  = 0x83da000
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
mmap2(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xb7736000
........
.......
```

Hope this will solve your problem, but if you want to know about each syscall made then read its man pages or specifically ask about a syscall.

Comment: Its works fine for me but I used "strace -c kdir test " to organize the output.

Comment: great your problem has been solved. you ultimate destination will Intel Pin binary instrumentation if you have long term planning to work in kernel level

Answer (score 3):

Shortly:

```
strace command [arguments]
```

For example:

```
strace mkdir test
```

For more info, see `man strace`.