# Does every program have to go through the shell to complete the process they willing to make?

Tags: command-line, kernel, bash, gui

I have seen somewhere that "bash is used to communicate with the Linux kernel."

Is it applicable only to the terminal? Or does every program (including programs which has GUIs) have to go through the shell to complete the process they willing to make?

(Consider we are coloring a photo. How does bash know what we are doing? Is there a third party between gimp and bash to convert them to bash?)

It would be really helpful if can you take an example to explain :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nope. Only users have to go through a shell to communicate with the Kernel. Applications use [APIs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_programming_interface).

For example, if I want to delete a file, I have to use one shell or the other, and then an application to delete the file:

1. With a Command-Line Interface (CLI) shell, such as `bash`, I can use the `rm` command to delete the file.
2. With a GUI shell (like Unity, or GNOME Shell), I can use something else, such as the File Manager to delete the file. The GUI shell does not, in turn, need to use a CLI shell.

Both the File Manager and `rm` in turn may use the `unlink(3)` (or the higher level `remove(3)`) function (or [system call](https://askubuntu.com/questions/426897/how-do-i-know-the-system-call-for-a-particular-command)) to do the actual work.

Comment: | I have to use one shell or the other|how many shells are there in a OS? if it is gnome, are there only bash and gnome shell? or we can install many?

Comment: @Srinesh As many shells as you can find (though some may be incompatible with others).

Comment: @Srinesh by default , Ubuntu comes with `dash` (Debian Amquist Shell) and `bash` (Bourne Again Shell) , which are used for interactive and scripting purpose in text interface. Red Hat Linux on the other hand, comes with `bash` and `tcsh` . `Gnome` and `Unity` are graphical shells.   One can install as many as one wants, e.g., I've got `bash`, `dash`, `mksh` , `ksh`, `tcsh`, and `zsh` installed. For 99% of the day to day tasks, you can use `bash`. Developers, hackers, and just technical junkies , may have many of them installed. Why ? Because each shell has some set of unique features